# Sharepoint regression test

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

HI i need few ideas or sample on how to do regression test cases for SharePoint applications. I haven't done anything like this previously.would really helpful if someone could really provide me links or example on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to look for Coded UI test in VS2012. You did not mention if your version of SharePoint, so Ill just assume it is 2013.

All the features provided by Microsoft SharePoint 2013 can be tested using Coded UI tests with few exceptions.

Take a look on this article, this might help you get started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/25/ui-testing-of-microsoft-sharepoint-2013-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx

What I recommend you to do is to make small test cases on the core features on your solution. And then expand it later. Making it small and modular will hopefully make it maintainable. One of the easy pitfalls is to make really large and throughout test cases, that will be hard to alter later.

Good luck